# Where do extra parameters come from?

Tags: 8

Not a real issue but more of an informative question.

Concrete case:

**system.routing.yml** integrates **system.entity_autocomplete** that uses `controller::method`

`\Drupal\system\Controller\EntityAutocompleteController::handleAutocomplete`. First parameter in `handleAutocomplete()` is `$request` and the rest are the ones we could explect from url.

Where did `$request` come from?

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature [provided by Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller.html#the-request-object-as-a-controller-argument):

> ## The Request object as a Controller Argument
>
> What if you need to read query parameters, grab a request header or get access to an uploaded file? All of that information is stored in Symfony's Request object. To get it in your controller, just add it as an argument and type-hint it with the Request class:
>
> ```
> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
>
> public function indexAction(Request $request, $firstName, $lastName)
> {
>   $page = $request->query->get('page', 1);
>
>   // ...
> }
> ```